# JMockit - verify private method

Tags: java, testing, jmockit

The method below has 3 possible paths:
1. True,
2. False,
3. Exception.

To test it, I need to mock the private `getWootsWithAvailableProducts` for the `True` and `Exception` paths.  However, the collective wisdom seems to be saying that you should not mock private methods. How else can I test those paths if I don't mock the private method, and spy on it for verification.  If that's all true, why is it so hard to mock private methods.  If its not true, what am I missing?

Under test:

```
  public List<Woot> findAllWoots(final boolean isBuy) throws Exception {

    final List<Woot> allWoots = wootService.findAllWoots();

    return isBuy ? getWootsWithAvailableProducts(allWoots) : allWoots;
  }
```

Futher details:

`getWootsWithAvailableProducts` calls a public service that makes a network request.  So, I can mock the actual service class and prevent any net requests from occurring.

```
private List<Woot> getWootsWithAvailableProducts(List<Woot> allWoots)
    throws ServiceException {

    final String stringOfWootIds = buildStringOfCommaSeparatedIDs(allWoots);
    final List<Count> categoryIDs = wootSearchService
        .getWootIDsOfAvailableProducts(stringOfWootIds);

    return filterOnlyWootsWithAvailProducts(allCategories, categoryIDs);// also private.
}
```

Comment: Are there any knock on effects of calling `getWootsWithAvailableProducts`?

Comment: Yes, it calls a service that makes a network request.

Comment: that is an external dependency that should be abstracted out into its own concern as it is tightly coupling your code and making it difficult to test in isolation.

Comment: This means either that: 1. Your network service dependency is hidden and cannot be mocked and your class is needlessly coupled to it; 2. Your class does too much; 3. (very probable) Your idea of testing is incorrect and your tests will be very tightly coupled to the tested classes. Widen out your test scope and write tests as a unit specification, not a test per each if/else branch.

Comment: There are only two paths in that method, not three. The collective wisdom is right about not mocking private methods, since they are merely implementation details. The important thing to understand about automated developer tests, in general, is that they should test *meaningful functionality*, and nothing more; a good test cares only about verifying a "business" feature of some part of the SUT, it does not care about pieces of code. And mocking is best not used at all, if possible. Use it only when strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments it was indicated that `getWootsWithAvailableProducts`

> calls a service that makes a network request

That is an external dependency that should be abstracted out into its own concern as it is tightly coupling your code and making it difficult to test in isolation.

```
public interface WootProductsService {
    List<Woot> getWootsWithAvailableProducts(List<Woot> woots);
}
```

The implementation of said abstractions will encapsulate the network calls, decoupling the original code so that the abstraction can be mocked when testing the method in isolation.

```
WootProductsService wootProductService; //Injected

public List<Woot> findAllWoots(final boolean isBuy) throws Exception {

    final List<Woot> allWoots = wootService.findAllWoots();

    return isBuy ? wootProductService.getWootsWithAvailableProducts(allWoots) : allWoots;
}
```

You now have control of all the dependencies and can manipulate them as desired when testing for all scenarios.

Pay attention to the concerns of your methods and by extension, classes, as they will indicate if your class is doing too much.

When encountering problem in testing your code, take that as a sign that something is not right with its design. Review the cause of the problem and consider what refactors need to be applied to make the code more SOLID.

Comment: I updated the question with more details, which I believe is what you're talking about.  For instance, the service class is mocked with `@Injected` and its public in the class under test.  Still I can't even see the private method within the test code, and making it public doesn't seem right, though I suppose that could be an answer.

Comment: @nullsteph You are focusing too much on testing the private method. As already mentioned, focus on the public method and testing that it behaves as expected. Mock any dependencies that will allow the method under test to be exercised to completion given the possible scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I didn't want to test this method in this test, just confirm it was called.  This test now just verifies the two return types; List and Exception

Answer (score 0):

You can write tests for the accessible methods from which this private method is being called and then test all possible outcomes

Also, please ensure you are mocking other class functions and all variables which otherwise may cause issue while executing private function while testing.

So basically, you will be testing possible scenarios like this:

Public function when private function returns

1. true
2. false
3. exception

Hope that helps.